# Change name of a column value based on a second columns date and time

Tags: r

I have a dataset of over 10,000obs that lists detections of 39 fish via a transceiver with a specific serial number for each fish. There is a column of detected tag serial numbers (transmitter_id), a column of date-times of each detection (detection_timestamp_EST), and a simpler column naming the fish by number (Fish_ID), just for graphing purposes.

One tag was with fish "21", up until "2020-11-06 14:05:00," when it was given to fish "39." From this point on, Fish 21 is not in the study.

I'm hoping to change the name of tag "A69-1602-59219" to "A69-1602-59219R" when it occurs after "2020-11-06 14:05:00" so that I can analyze the two fishes' data independently.

This will allow me to use:

```
dets2$Fish_ID <- gsub("A69-1602-59219R" , "39", dets2$Fish_ID)
```

to create fish 39 in Fish_ID for graphing

This is what I've tried, and it doesn't give an error, but it doesn't seem to do what I need:

```
 dets2 %>% mutate(transmitter_id = 
                     ifelse(detection_timestamp_est >= "2020-11-06 14:05:00" 
                      & transmitter_id == "A69-1602-59219", 
                      "A69-1602-59219R", transmitter_id))
```

Here's a snippet of the data:

| transmitter_id | detection_timestamp_est | Fish_ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A69-1602-59219 | 2020-11-02 12:28:05 | 21 |
| A69-1602-59219 | 2020-11-06 15:17:12 | 21 |
| A69-1602-53428 | 2020-11-02 08:15:29 | 34 |
| A69-1602-23335 | 2020-11-03 18:42:03 | 19 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We may use `case_when` - use `as.POSIXct` to convert the string to `Datetime` class

```
library(dplyr)
dets3 <- dets2 %>% 
    mutate(transmitter_id = 
                     case_when(detection_timestamp_est >= as.POSIXct("2020-11-06 14:05:00")
                      & transmitter_id == "A69-1602-59219"~ 
                      "A69-1602-59219R", TRUE ~ transmitter_id))
```

-output

```
dets3
dets3
   transmitter_id detection_timestamp_est Fish_ID
1  A69-1602-59219     2020-11-02 12:28:05      21
2 A69-1602-59219R     2020-11-06 15:17:12      21
3  A69-1602-53428     2020-11-02 08:15:29      34
4  A69-1602-23335     2020-11-03 18:42:03      19
```

#### data

```
dets2 <- structure(list(transmitter_id = c("A69-1602-59219", "A69-1602-59219", 
"A69-1602-53428", "A69-1602-23335"), detection_timestamp_est = structure(c(1604338085, 
1604693832, 1604322929, 1604446923), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
), tzone = ""), Fish_ID = c(21L, 21L, 34L, 19L)), row.names = c(NA, 
-4L), class = "data.frame")
```